# Adding values of two separate int vectors with different sizes?

Tags: c++, math, vector, sum, addition

I am wondering how I could add the values of two vectors, like so:

```
vector<int> v1 = {3, 1, 7};
vector<int> v2 = {6, 5};
vector<int> v3 = {3, 8, 2}; // The sum of v1 and v2
```

The result here should be 382, as 317 + 65 yields 382.

Is there a way to do this? The sizes of the vectors are quite tricky. For example, the 2nd element in v1 is 1, but the 2nd element in v2 is 5. However, 5 must be added to the 7, not the 1.

*edit:* Forgot to mention that the vectors can be infinitely long. Casting to an int and then back to a vector could cause loss of numbers.

Comment: *Is there a way to do this?* -- Since this is what you asked, the answer is "Yes".  Vectors can be resized -- just stick 0's in the beginning of the smaller vector so that it is the same size as the larger vector.

Comment: Are you trying to do arbitrary-length addition, where the vectors could be many digits?

Comment: ok.  Once you resize the smaller vector to equal the larger vector, you just iterate from the back to the front, adding to a new vector and saving a carry, similar to elementary schoolbook addition.  Also since this a project, it wouldn't be wise to post a solution -- if you make a good faith attempt and get stuck, then you can post your code.

Comment: Another hint -- since your container is `std::vector`, you probably may want to reverse the vectors (see `std::reverse`) before doing anything.  The reason is that it is more efficient in the long run to work with reversed numbers when dealing with vectors.  For reversed vectors, you would call `push_back` which is more efficient than trying to insert at the head of a long vector for each digit. Then you iterate from front to back, and at the end reverse the resulting vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That makes sense. The reverse is actually helpful, because I was using `insert` at the beginning instead of `push_back`. Also, I didn't think about resizing it, adding those extra 0's at the end. Thanks for your advice, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple approach I devised on the conditions required: (considering vectors `v1` and `v2`, of data type `DT`)

- **Size difference:** For cases where the vectors are of unequal sizes, you can simply append `0` at the end by using `std::vector<>::insert(iterator, 0)` with the iterator set to the beginning, since you'll need the zeroes to come first for proper element-to-element addition. Prior to that though, check which of the two vectors is larger in size, then collect the difference and insert for the same amount of times in a loop:

```cpp
   int diff;
   if(v1.size() > v2.size())
   {  diff = v1.size() - v2.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
          v2.insert(v2.begin(), 0);
   }          
   else
   {  diff = v2.size() - v1.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
          v1.insert(v1.begin(), 0);
   }
```

- **Addition:** Now that the vectors are of equal sizes, you can use `std::plus` from the `functional` header for adding elements of one vector (say `v1`) to the other vector (`v2`) element-wise, emplaced with proper iterator positions in a `std::transform`:

```cpp
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v1.begin(), std::plus<DT>());
```

This will collect the element-wise sum of `v1` and `v2` into `v1` (interchangeable). The only remaining issue or condition to deal with is the overflow for cases when element-wise additions sum up to be greater than or equal to 10.

- **Overflow:** For all the elements in the vector apart from the first one (at 0<sup>th</sup> index), we will need to carry/add `1` to the next element in cases of overflow (`>=10`) and assign the current vector element to its remainder when divided by 10. However, for the first element to overflow, we'll need to assign another element to the vector's beginning (eg: {3, 1} + {9, 2} = {1, 2, 3}) , which will be a `1` again (considering single digit vector elements), for which we can impose seperate `if` statements:

```cpp
   for(int i = v1.size(); i > 0; --i) 
   { 
       if(i == 1 && v1[1] >= 10)
       {   v1[1] %= 10;
           v1.insert(v1.begin(), 1);
       }     
       else if(i != 1 && v1[i-1] >= 10)
       {  v1[i - 1] %= 10;
          v1[i - 2] += 1;
       }
   }
```

---

Examples:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#define DT long long int
int main() 
{   
    std::vector<DT> v1 = {5, 2, 5, 7, 8}; 
    std::vector<DT> v2 = {4, 5, 6};  

                         // 52578
                         // 00456
                         // -----
   // Expected output:   // 53034   
   
   // Size management:
   int diff;
   if(v1.size() > v2.size())
   {  diff = v1.size() - v2.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
          v2.insert(v2.begin(), 0);
   }          
   else
   {  diff = v2.size() - v1.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
          v1.insert(v1.begin(), 0);
   }
   
   // Element-wise addition:
   std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v1.begin(),std::plus<DT>());
   
   // Overflow management:
   for(int i = v1.size(); i > 0; --i) 
   { 
       if(i == 1 && v1[1] >= 10)
       {   v1[1] %= 10;
           v1.insert(v1.begin(), 1);
       }     
       else if(i != 1 && v1[i - 1] >= 10)
       {  v1[i - 1] %= 10;
          v1[i - 2] += 1;
       }
   }   
   
   // Display the sum:
   for(auto v:v1)
      std::cout << v;
}
```

Output: `53034`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#define DT long long int
int main() 
{   
    std::vector<DT> v1 = {5, 2, 5, 7}; 
    std::vector<DT> v2 = {9, 3, 7, 2};  

                         //  5257
                         //  9372
                         // -----
   // Expected output:   // 14629   
   
   // Size management:
   int diff;
   if(v1.size() > v2.size())
   {  diff = v1.size() - v2.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
          v2.insert(v2.begin(), 0);
   }          
   else
   {  diff = v2.size() - v1.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
          v1.insert(v1.begin(), 0);
   }
   
   // Element-wise addition:
   std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v1.begin(),std::plus<DT>());
   
   // Overflow management:
   for(int i = v1.size(); i > 0; --i) 
   { 
       if(i == 1 && v1[1] >= 10)
       {   v1[1] %= 10;
           v1.insert(v1.begin(), 1);
       }     
       else if(i != 1 && v1[i-1] >= 10)
       {  v1[i - 1] %= 10;
          v1[i - 2] += 1;
       }
   }   
   
   // Display the sum:
   for(auto v:v1)
      std::cout << v;
}
```

Output: `14629`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you want something like this?:

This code, first makes v1, v2 vectors to integers n1, n2

And does integer sum adding up to n3.

And after that, make integer n3 into vector again.

```
vector<int> v1 = {3, 1, 7};
vector<int> v2 = {6, 5};
vector<int> v3;// = {3, 8, 2}; // The sum of v1 and v2
int n1=0; for(int a:v1) n1=10*n1+a;
int n2=0; for(int a:v2) n2=10*n2+a;
int n3 = n1 + n2;
while(n3) v3.insert(v3.begin(), n3%10),n3/=10;
//now v3 = {3, 8, 2}
```

Comment: Does this work if v1 = `{9, 9, 9}` and v2 = `{9, 9, 9}`?

Comment: ok, I tested it and it works for carry's beyond the most significant digit.

Comment: I would upvote your code, except there are so many statements on the same line. The while statement which uses comma `,` to chain expressions is particularly bad.

Comment: The one problem with this is that you are limited to `int` sized values, thus possible overflow can happen.  Usually, this type of problem is done to solve the "arbitrary length" addition problem, and your code doesn't do this.

Comment: Yes, the OP wants arbitrarily long numbers, so this solution won't work beyond `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Comment: Why are there 3 upvotes? This post does not answer the question of the OP. It will work only for very small vectors.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to iterate through the vectors in reverse.

```
std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator first = v1.rbegin(), endfirst = v1.rend();
std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator second = v2.rbegin(), endsecond = v2.rend();

//   if adding two digits gives a value of 10 or more, need to carry

int carry = 0;
std::vector<int> v3(0);
//  first do summations of digits in reverse until one vector has no more

//   the following loops will collect digits in v3 (the notional "sum" of v1 and v2)
//      in reverse order

while (first != endfirst && second != endsecond)
{

     int sum = *first + *second + carry;
     carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
     v3.push_back(sum % 10);
     ++first; ++second;
}

//    if we have reached the end of v1, there may be additional elements in v2, so     

if (first == firstend)
{
     first = second;
     firstend = secondend;
}

//   first and firstend specify the range in whichever vector (v1 or v2) has 
//       more elements
//    The next loop does nothing if v1 and v2 have the same length

while (first != firstend)
{
     int sum = *first + carry;
     carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
     v3.push_back(sum % 10);
     ++first;
}

//   if we are carrying a digit after doing all the sums, then push a 1

if (carry) v3.push_back(1);

//   we have pushed the digits into v3 in reverse order, so ....

std::reverse(v3.begin(), v3.end());
```

This will handle vectors of any valid length.   (I'll leave the problem of finding hardware that can represent vectors of infinite length as an unresolved challenge).

The code above assumes all the elements of `v1` and `v2` are in the range `0` to `9`.    It can be trivially modified to handle elements with value `10` or more.  I'll leave that as an exercise.

It is possible reduce memory allocation/reallocation when pushing elements into `v3` by a call to `v3.reserve()`.   I'll leave that as an exercise.